# Running Tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, keras

I am trying to do some deep learning work. For this, I first installed all the packages for deep learning in my Python environment.

Here is what I did.

In Anaconda, I created an environment called `tensorflow` as follows

```
conda create -n tensorflow
```

Then installed the data science Python packages, like Pandas, NumPy, etc., inside it. I also installed TensorFlow and Keras there. Here is the list of packages in that environment

```
(tensorflow) SFOM00618927A:dl i854319$ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/i854319/anaconda/envs/tensorflow:
#
appdirs                   1.4.3                     <pip>
appnope                   0.1.0                    py36_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.5.3                    py36_0  
bleach                    1.5.0                    py36_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0  
decorator                 4.0.11                   py36_0  
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py36_1  
freetype                  2.5.5                         2  
html5lib                  0.999                    py36_0  
icu                       54.1                          0  
ipykernel                 4.5.2                    py36_0  
ipython                   5.3.0                    py36_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0  
ipywidgets                6.0.0                    py36_0  
jinja2                    2.9.5                    py36_0  
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py36_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_3  
jupyter_client            5.0.0                    py36_0  
jupyter_console           5.1.0                    py36_0  
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py36_0  
Keras                     2.0.2                     <pip>
libpng                    1.6.27                        0  
markupsafe                0.23                     py36_2  
matplotlib                2.0.0               np112py36_0  
mistune                   0.7.4                    py36_0  
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0  
nbconvert                 5.1.1                    py36_0  
nbformat                  4.3.0                    py36_0  
notebook                  4.4.1                    py36_0  
numpy                     1.12.1                    <pip>
numpy                     1.12.1                   py36_0  
openssl                   1.0.2k                        1  
packaging                 16.8                      <pip>
pandas                    0.19.2              np112py36_1  
pandocfilters             1.4.1                    py36_0  
path.py                   10.1                     py36_0  
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_0  
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1  
prompt_toolkit            1.0.13                   py36_0  
protobuf                  3.2.0                     <pip>
ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py36_0  
pygments                  2.2.0                    py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.2.0                     <pip>
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_2  
python                    3.6.1                         0  
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py36_0  
pytz                      2017.2                   py36_0  
PyYAML                    3.12                      <pip>
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py36_0  
qt                        5.6.2                         0  
qtconsole                 4.3.0                    py36_0  
readline                  6.2                           2  
scikit-learn              0.18.1              np112py36_1  
scipy                     0.19.0              np112py36_0  
setuptools                34.3.3                    <pip>
setuptools                27.2.0                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_1  
sip                       4.18                     py36_0  
six                       1.10.0                    <pip>
six                       1.10.0                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
tensorflow                1.0.1                     <pip>
terminado                 0.6                      py36_0  
testpath                  0.3                      py36_0  
Theano                    0.9.0                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
tornado                   4.4.2                    py36_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0  
wheel                     0.29.0                    <pip>
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0  
widgetsnbextension        2.0.0                    py36_0  
xz                        5.2.2                         1  
zlib                      1.2.8                         3  
(tensorflow) SFOM00618927A:dl i854319$
```

You can see that `jupyter` is also installed.

Now, when I open up the Python interpreter in this environment and I run the basic TensorFlow command, it all works fine.  However, I wanted to do the same thing in the Jupyter notebook. So, I created a new directory (outside of this environment).

```
mkdir dl
```

In that, I activated `tensorflow` environment

```
SFOM00618927A:dl i854319$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) SFOM00618927A:dl i854319$ conda list
```

And I can see the same list of packages in that.

Now, I open up a Jupyter notebook

```
SFOM00618927A:dl i854319$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) SFOM00618927A:dl i854319$ jupyter notebook
```

It opens up a new notebook in the browser. But when I just import basic python libraries in that, like pandas, it says "no packages available". I am not sure why is that when the same environment has all those packages and in the same directory, if I use Python interpreter it shows all packages.

```
import pandas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d6ac987968b6> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Why jupyter notebook is not picking up these modules?

So, Jupyter notebook doesn't show env as the interpreter

[image]

Comment: Have you also chosen your `env` as a notebook `python` interpreter when you were creating your notebook?

Comment: I am not sure I understand that?. I just activated the environment in the same directory and then called Jupyter from that environment. Could you guide how to do what you are mentioning?

Comment: In the top right corner you should have a `notebook` interpreter. Could you check which one is set for your notebook?

Comment: I selected Python3

Comment: You should have your `env` as an option, don't you?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I should have tensorflow (which is the env name) as one of the option. But I dont.. Thats strange. I thought if you activate a conda env then open jupyter notebook from there it should have that env displayed. It doesn't. Attached screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139906/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-baktaawar).

Answer (score 55):

I came up with your case. This is how I sort it out

1. Install Anaconda
2. Create a virtual environment - `conda create -n tensorflow`
3. Go inside your virtual environment - (on macOS/Linux:) `source activate tensorflow` (on Windows: `activate tensorflow`)
4. Inside that install tensorflow. You can install it using `pip`
5. Finish install

So then the next thing, when you launch it:

6. If you are not inside the virtual environment type - `Source Activate  Tensorflow`
7. Then inside this again install your Jupiter notebook and Pandas  libraries, because there can be some missing in this virtual environment

Inside the virtual environment just type:

8. `pip install jupyter notebook`
9. `pip install pandas`

Then you can launch jupyter notebook saying:

10. `jupyter notebook`
11. Select the correct terminal python 3 or 2
12. Then import those modules

Comment: There is something wrong with data science, how can people get into it with such a difficult setup...

Comment: This is what happens when you work with new stuff. Once things settle down and standards are created, then it'll be a click of a button. 15 years ago when CSS first came out, getting it to work consistently across IE5/6 and Netscape was a complete nightmare.

Comment: @JuanBoero The problem is that none of the "code-heads" that build this stuff have ever had to walk their completely non-technical CEO through the installation and setup with him/her screaming that them the whole time as to why it is so complicated.

Answer (score 28):

I believe a short video showing all the details if you have Anaconda is the following for mac (it is very similar to windows users as well) just open Anaconda navigator and everything is just the same (almost!)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDzAm25CORk

Then go to jupyter notebook and code

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

Then

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It work for me! :)

Comment: very strangely this works. I think this issue is only experienced in old package versions on pip installations that may rely on kernel references

Comment: Hello @bmbigbang it might be the case, but I also downloaded the new version of pip and it did the same strange behaviour, therefore, I thought of putting my answer to that question.

Answer (score 10):

1. Install Anaconda
2. Run Anaconda command prompt
3. write "activate tensorflow" for windows
4. pip install tensorflow
5. pip install jupyter notebook
6. jupyter notebook.

Only this solution worked for me. Tried 7 8 solutions. 
Using Windows platform.

Answer (score 7):

1. install tensorflow by running these commands in anoconda shell or in console:

   ```
   conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
   activate tensorflow
   conda install pandas matplotlib jupyter notebook scipy scikit-learn
   pip install tensorflow
   ```
2. close the console and reopen it and type these commands:

   ```
   activate tensorflow 
   jupyter notebook
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a fairly simple way to do this.

Initially, through your Anaconda Prompt, you can follow the steps in this official Tensorflow site - [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). You have to follow the steps as is, no deviation.

Later, you open the Anaconda Navigator. In Anaconda Navigator, go to Applications On --- section. Select the drop down list, after following above steps you must see an entry - tensorflow into it. Select tensorflow and let the environment load.

Then, select Jupyter Notebook in this new context, and install it, let the installation get over.

After that you can run the Jupyter notebook like the regular notebook in tensorflow environment.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest launching Jupyter lab/notebook from your base environment and selecting the right kernel.

[How to add conda environment to jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004311/how-to-add-conda-environment-to-jupyter-lab) should contains the info needed to add the kernel to your base environment.

Disclaimer : I asked the question in the topic I linked, but I feel it answers your problem too.

Answer (score 1):

For Anaconda users in Windows 10 and those who recently updated Anaconda environment, TensorFlow may cause some issues to activate or initiate. 
Here is the solution which I explored and which worked for me:

- Uninstall current Anaconda environment and delete all the existing files associated with Anaconda from your C:\Users or where ever you installed it.
- Download Anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/download/?lang=en-us#windows)
- While installing, check the "Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable"
- After installing, open the Anaconda command prompt to install TensorFlow using these steps:
- Create a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

  > conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
  >   (Use this command even if you are using python 3.6 because TensorFlow will get upgraded in the following steps)
- Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

  > activate tensorflow 
  >   After this step, the command prompt will change to (tensorflow)
- After activating, upgrade tensorflow using this command:

  > pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade
  >   Now you have successfully installed the CPU version of TensorFlow.
- Close the Anaconda command prompt and open it again and activate the tensorflow environment using 'activate tensorflow' command.
- Inside the tensorflow environment, install the following libraries using the commands:
  pip install jupyter
  pip install keras
  pip install pandas
  pip install pandas-datareader
  pip install matplotlib
  pip install scipy
  pip install sklearn
- Now your tensorflow environment contains all the common libraries used in deep learning.
- Congrats, these libraries will make you ready to build deep neural nets. If you need more libraries install using the same command 'pip install libraryname'

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a "kernel" for it.
Run your enviroment:

```
>activate tensorflow
```

Then add a kernel by command (after --name should follow your env. with tensorflow):

```
>python -m ipykernel install --user --name tensorflow --display-name "TensorFlow-GPU"
```

After that run jupyter notebook from your tensorflow env.

```
>jupyter notebook
```

And then you will see the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0iC3.jpg)

Click on it and then in the notebook import packages. It will work out for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create new environment with new name ($newenv):`conda create -n $newenv tensorflow`

Then by using anaconda navigator under environment tab you can find newenv in the middle column.

By clicking on the play button open terminal and type: `activate tensorflow`

Then install tensorflow inside the newenv by typing: `pip install tensorflow`

Now you have tensorflow inside the new environment so then install jupyter by typing: `pip install jupyter notebook`

Then just simply type: `jupyter notebook` to run the jupyter notebook.

Inside of the jupyter notebook type: `import tensorflow as tf`

To test the the tf you can use [THIS LINK](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a long time after this question is being asked since I was searching so much for the same problem and couldn't find the extant solutions helpful, I write what fixed my trouble for anyone with the same issue:
The point is, Jupyter should be installed in your virtual environment, meaning, after activating the `tensorflow` environment, run the following in the command prompt (**in `tensorflow` virtual environment**):

```
conda install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

and then the jupyter will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I have to install it using condo's pip3. Just start jupyter-notebook and execute following

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

This will give you something like this

```
/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Now in a terminal execute the following (using pip3 from the above path where we found our python)

```
/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin/pip3 install tensorflow
```

This is basically installing the Tensorflow in the Conda environment using the Conda pip3 installer