# how to fix no module name tensorflow in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am facing the problem where tensorflow is not running in the jupyter notebook it is showing me

```
No module named tensorflow
```

But it is running ine anaconda prompt how to fix this

[image]

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221181/no-module-named-tensorflow-in-jupyter/43967691

Comment: @JoeA I have tried all the stuff but this is not working

Comment: Have you tried a conda install pip and then install tensorflow via pip or pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: I have tried pip3 install -upgrade tensorflow but it didnot worked

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would try it this:

First create a new environment:

```
conda create -n test_tensor
```

Second we can activate that enviornment now that we created using the source command:

```
source activate test_tensor
```

Then we can install pip:

```
conda install pip
```

The we can installTensorFlow

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

These links could help also:

[Trouble with TensorFlow in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061089/trouble-with-tensorflow-in-jupyter-notebook)

[Running Tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216256/running-tensorflow-in-jupyter-notebook/43259471)